# Mandrill integration not sending email for front-end registration form

Tags: form, emails, registration

**Update** Emails only send out when you're not logged in as admin from the registration form.

No errors received in dev mode, user created, but no activation email sent. Definitely not getting passed to Mandrill as [Little Snitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch) checks outgoing connections.

- The weird thing is, user activation from the admin **does** send an activation email.
- Verify email addresses? in `system > users` is selected.

It should send an activation email out, right? Or are you supposed to activate every new user via admin?

Comment: You're connecting to Mandrill through SMTP under Settings->Email in the control panel?

Comment: Yes, SMTP authentication selected and Mandrill username (email) and password (API key) same as [their docs](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582197-Where-do-I-find-my-SMTP-credentials-) — as I've said `user > settings > send activation email` works as expected.

Comment: If you check under `Users` in the control panel, is the user being created?

Comment: D'oh! I don't know why I didn't realise my mistake earlier — I've been trying to create an account when logged in as admin. No wonder :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emails only send out when you're **not logged in as admin** from the front-end registration form.